# Javascript link rendered without onclick attribute in preview

Tags: glass-mapper, links, javascript, link-manager, renderfield

When using javascript link the edit mode renders the target script in onClick attribute

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:void(0);onclick=javascript:openOverlay('test-overlay',event);return false;" class="vds-button" sc-part-of="field">Show Test Modal</a>
```

Preview mode renders target script in href attribute

```
<a href="javascript:openOverlay('test-overlay', event)" class="vds-button">Show Test Modal</a>
```

is there any workaround to get the preview mode work same as edit mode to render javascript links?

Update 1:
It appears to be something to do with glassmapper escaping Sitecore renderfield processor in preview/live mode. Any thoughts/suggestions on customizing glassmapper to resolve this?

Any help towards overriding glassmapper as explained here - [RenderField pipeline only called in editing mode](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/98#issuecomment-430666909) would be appreciated.

**Update 2:**

Following this https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/custom-glass-mapper-data-handlers-part-2/ I've managed to add a onclick Property to Glass Link field

```
 public class GlassLinkFieldDataMapper : SitecoreFieldLinkMapper
{
    public override object GetField(Field field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
    {
        var link = (Link)base.GetField(field, config, context);

        if(link!=null && link.Type== LinkType.Javascript && link.Url.Contains("openOverlay"))
        {
            var extendedLink = new ExtendedLink(link);
            extendedLink.Url = "#";
            return extendedLink;
        }

        return link;
    }
}

public class ExtendedLink : Link
{
    public ExtendedLink(Link link)
    {
        base.Class = link.Class;
        base.Text = link.Text;
        this.onClick = link.Url;
    }

    public string onClick { get; set; }
}
```

But not sure how to have this onClick property rendered as attribute, as I see no option on Glass Link Field class, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**From the API:**

You can analyze the `Sitecore.Context.Site.DisplayMode` property.

1. It is equal to the `Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Edit` value in the `webedit mode`.
2. `Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Preview` value in the `preview mode` and
3. `Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Normal` in the `normal mode`.

**In Glassmapper:**

1. `Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode` for `webedit mode`

by using the above properties you can build/render your condition base code.

**Example:**

```
if (Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode)
{
  // code-a 
}
else
{
 //code-b
}
```

Comment: I knew I can do this, but it isn't for one instance of rendering, I'd like it to work for any link which has javascript on it.